# Selenium click a link

Tags: python, selenium

I have been facing a major issue while using selenium:

On the Trivago website "https://www.trivago.com/site_map", I have been trying to get the script to click on each continent but it seems to not work:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('link')

element.click()
```

I also attempted by xpath using the following:

```
//*[@id="js_sitemap"]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: The continent links on that site are available as URLs. Why do you need selenium at all? Just open the URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to click on `li` node while you need to handle child link:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.link>a').click()
```

But if you want to open page of each continent you'd better to get list of references and get each of them:

```
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.link>a')]

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    # do something with continent
```

Answer (score 1):

As @DyZ pointed out, you can simply scrape the listings by using the urls provided on the page, such as `'https://www.trivago.com/north-america-34225/hotel'`. However, you can iterate over `find_elements_by_tag_name` and call the `click` method for each object reference:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jamespetullo/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.trivago.com/site_map')
for continent in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
   if continent.text in [u'Africa', u'Asia', u'Australia & Oceania', u'Central and South America', u'Europe', u'North America']:
      continent.click()
      #do something with page source or current page object
      d.back()
```

Alternatively, to find the links, you can use `bs4` and `urllib`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib
import re
data = str(urllib.urlopen('https://www.trivago.com/site_map').read())
links = [i.text for i in soup(data, 'lxml').find_all('a', href=True) if re.findall('[a-zA-Z\-]+\-\d+/hotel', i['href'])]
```

Output:

```
[u'Africa', u'Asia', u'Australia & Oceania', u'Central and South America', u'Europe', u'North America']
```

Comment: Nice one, but IMHO not the most elegant way... I think if you know the text of each link it's better to make it like this: `for continent in [u'Africa', u'Asia', u'Australia & Oceania', u'Central and South America', u'Europe', u'North America']: driver.find_element_by_link_text(continent).click()`. Also note that you need `driver.back()` or `driver.get("https://www.trivago.com/site_map")` on each iteration

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for pointing out `driver.back()`. TBH I think that using `bs4` to find the continents and then iterating over the list like you have suggested is the optimal way, although it seems that the OP wishes to utilize purely `selenium`.